# How to enable ligatures

Tags: ligatures

I just notice that ligatures are not working on my system. For example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\renewcommand{\rmdefault}{ptm}
\begin{document}
data-flow missing ligature.
\end{document}
```

The "flow" word does not use the f-l ligature, appearing ugly.

[image]

This also happens with the default article font (if I removed the `renewcommand`):

[image]

I am setting with pdflatex.

Do I have to include a particular package?

Comment: There are ligatures. Compare with `f\/low`, or try the fi ligature.

Comment: Try `f\/low` to explicitely prevent a ligature.

Comment: Ok, I see the difference. So the problem then is just that in these fonts, the f-l ligature is extremely ugly? For me it looks just as if the kerning is smaller and the two characters are moved together to overlap. The f-i ligature looks correct, though.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

sorry to say, this *is* the `fl` ligature.

here is the output of running `tex testfont` on `ptmr7t` (the roman
instance of the ptm fonts):

[image: font table of font ptmr7t]